# How to buy in modal window homepage Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to implement the purchasing functionality on the main page in the modal window, with subsequent registrations. This is similar to the "Checkout" page, only on the main page.

For example:
1) There are 4 packages on the main page. When you click on one package, the modal window "Bootstrap 4" opens. When you click on any package, the same modal window opens.

2) In the modal window there will be a registration form "User data such as Name and phone, etc."

3) There are also 4 packages at different prices from the bottom, you need to select one package for the user.

4) There is only one payment system. Fills out the card data and upon successful payment, moves to the personal cabinet.

It turns out that there will be only two pages on the site. one - Home, the other - My Account.

It will be more convenient for me to do it on Woocommerce.

I understand that the question may not be set correctly, but I tried to write down all the important details of the problem.

There are similar plug-ins such as "Quick purchase", but I do not know if there is a registration.

I did not find the answer to the question in Russian-language sites.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this plugin for woocommerce - [One page checkout](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-one-page-checkout/) with this plugin you can create a shortcode for your product just add that shortcode into your modal. and when modal popup user can checkout and register him self also.

[WordPress Plugin For Free](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bootstrap-one-page-woocommerce-checkout/)

Comment: This solution is for a fee.) Is it possible to have a free solution? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the solution